# How to center align div

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I got some embed code from Mail chimp to display a newsletter signup box on my website. I am trying to center align the newsletter box, but not sure what div I need to add the style to. I tried using style="text-align: center" but it didn't work. I think there might be an over riding style?

www.skinmade.com.au (see bottom of page)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give your containing div a fixed width, set display to 'block' and set left and right margin to 'auto' like this:

```
#mc_embed_signup {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:300px;
}
```

You can also fix the issue with your submit button not displaying the full text like this:

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
display: block;
width: 133px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
height: 43px;
/*margin:0;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input.button{ display: inline-block; }

#mc_embed_signup{ text-align:center; }
```

or

```
#mc_embed_signup{ width:200px; margin: auto auto; }
```

Comment: ok that worked, although it isn't inline with the icons above it. maybe it would look better on the same line as the icons. any suggestions on code?